# Exception in JBoss AS 7.2 CLI API when terminating connection

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

We recently upgraded from JBoss 7.1.3-Final to 7.2.0-Final. Since we upgraded one of our applications, that uses the Java CLI public API, throws NullPointerExceptions every time a connection is terminated through the CLI API.

The following is our code to set up and close the connection to the JBoss CLI:

```
private CommandContext ctx;
private ModelControllerClient client; 

public JBossCLITool() {
   try {
        ctx = CommandContextFactory.getInstance().newCommandContext();
    } catch(CliInitializationException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to initialize CLI context", e);
    }
}

public void establishConnection() {
    try {
        ctx.connectController("localhost", 9999);
        client = ctx.getModelControllerClient();
    } catch (CommandLineException e) {
        LOG.debug(e.toString());
    }
} 

public void terminateConnection() {
    try {
        if (!ctx.isTerminated()){
            ctx.terminateSession();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.debug(e.toString());
    }
}
```

when calling ctx.terminateSession() the following Exception is thrown:

```
13:46:58,691 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.handler-errors] (Remoting "cli-client" read-1) Close handler threw an exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.handleClose(CommandContextImpl.java:1206) [org-jboss-as-jboss-as-cli-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient$4.handleClose(CLIModelControllerClient.java:156) [org-jboss-as-jboss-as-cli-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CLIModelControllerClient$4.handleClose(CLIModelControllerClient.java:153) [org-jboss-as-jboss-as-cli-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.SpiUtils.safeHandleClose(SpiUtils.java:54) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable$CloseHandlerTask.run(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:501) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.runCloseTask(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:406) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.closeComplete(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:277) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionImpl.access$000(ConnectionImpl.java:38) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionImpl$1.handleClose(ConnectionImpl.java:55) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionImpl$1.handleClose(ConnectionImpl.java:53) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.SpiUtils.safeHandleClose(SpiUtils.java:54) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable$CloseHandlerTask.run(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:501) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.runCloseTask(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:406) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.spi.AbstractHandleableCloseable.closeComplete(AbstractHandleableCloseable.java:277) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionHandler.handleConnectionClose(RemoteConnectionHandler.java:117) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteReadListener.handleEvent(RemoteReadListener.java:78) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteReadListener.handleEvent(RemoteReadListener.java:45) [org-jboss-remoting3-jboss-remoting-3.2.14.GA.jar:3.2.14.GA]
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:189) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:103) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:189) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.ssl.JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.handleReadable(JsseConnectedSslStreamChannel.java:180) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:103) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-api-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-nio-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:187) [org-jboss-xnio-xnio-nio-3.0.7.GA.jar:3.0.7.GA]
```

Using the 7.1.3 API and JBoss AS the same code works fine. Even with 7.2 the connection seems to be closed correctly (after calling terminateSession() no further calls to the CLI can be made until I establish a new connection).

I asked the same question in the JBoss community, just repeating it hear in hope of somebody else seeing it. Here's the link: https://community.jboss.org/message/828608

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem.

To be serious, I haven't analyzed it in detail. Seems that it has something to do with the execution of composite DMRs - maybe in combination with a reload-required.

The parsedCommandLine in the CommandContext class is null. This is not checked by the close handler method.

As a first workaround I added a non invasive command before closing the context. I added the following line in my close method:

```
// Workaround for a strange NPE by jboss-cli I do not completely understand...
if (cmdCtx.getParsedCommandLine() == null
  || cmdCtx.getParsedCommandLine().getFormat() == null) {
  cmdCtx.handle("/:read-attribute(name=launch-type)");
}
if (!cmdCtx.isTerminated()) {
  cmdCtx.terminateSession();
}
```

Maybe not the best solution, but works on a first try...

Comment: To be more precise: getParsedCommandLine().getFormat() is null.